# Facebook background share from android app (facebook sdk 3.x)

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to share (Background without any share Dialog) on Facebook wall from my android app. I have used **Facebook (SDK 3.x)**. If possible please help me. Advance appreciation for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask the user for "publish_actions" permission, and then you can use the graph API to post to me/feed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed

See also the Request class in the Facebook SDK to help you make graph requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/

Comment: Facebook has done away with the publish_actions permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018