# Share to facebook from background - Android - Facebook SDK v4.x

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to be able to seamlessly publish to a users Facebook feed from the background in my Android application. The user is fully aware of the content they are publishing, but the post will be made after a relatively long upload process, so the user should not be made to wait. I am using the Android Facebook SDK v4.1.2.

I see that I need to request the `"publish_actions"` permission from the user beforehand:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-publish_actions

I can use the `LoginManager` to get the access token:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#access_profile

I am then not sure how to share a link to the users feed without using the `ShareDialog`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865976/facebook-background-share-from-android-app-facebook-sdk-3-x) suggests using the `Request` object for v3.x, which is equivalent to the `GraphRequest` object for v4.x:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/

but I am not sure how to build the correct `GraphRequest`. I assume I need to publish a message to `"/me/feed"`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ShareApi class if you don't want to build the params bundle yourself.

Build a ShareLinkContent as you normally would:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://your.url.com"))
    .build();
```

Then call ShareApi:

```
ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

In writing the question I found my own solution from trawling the docs and examples. I need to publish a message to `"/me/feed"`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("link", link);

GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

        }
    });
request.executeAndWait();
```

After obtaining the `"publish_actions"` permission.